# REST API: One Magento refuses to accept tokens

Tags: magento2.2, api, rest-api

I have a weird problem- I am trying to use the REST API in Magento 2. I am using exactly the same method with two other Magento installations successfully, and I was looking for some help debugging the one Magento install that doesn't work.

Here is an example request:

```
GET http://magento.xxxxx.co.uk/magento/rest/default/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=processing&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Authorization: bearer XXXXXXXX
Host: magento.xxxxx.co.uk
```

On my working Magento server I get back

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 03 Jul 2018 21:31:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.33 (Fedora)
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.19
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=a0bei0u4otg7122a918lsh3aje; expires=Tue, 03-Jul-2018 22:31:32 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/magento; domain=magento.xxxxxx.co.uk; HttpOnly
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 124926

{"items":[{"applied_rule_ids":"1","base_currency_code":"GBP","base_discount_amount":0,"base_discount_invoiced":0,"base_grand_total":36.39,"base_discount_tax_compensation_amount":0,"base_discount_tax_compensation_invoiced":0,"base_shipping_amount":5,"base_shipping_discount_amount":0,"base_shipping_incl_tax":5,"base_shipping_invoiced":5,"base_shipping_tax_amount":0,"base_subtotal":29,"base_subtotal_incl_tax":31.39,"base_subtotal_invoiced":29,"base_tax_amount":2.39,"base_tax_invoiced":2.39,"base_total_due":0,"base_total_invoiced":36.39,"base_total_invoiced_cost":0,"base_total_paid":36.39,"base_to_global_rate":1,"base_to_order_rate":1,"billing_address_id":2,"created_at":"2018-02-20 23:04:14","customer_dob":"1973-12-15 00:00:00","customer_email":"roni_cost@example.com","customer_firstname":"Veronica","customer_gender":2,"customer_group_id":1,"customer_id":1,"customer_is_guest":0,"customer_lastname":"Costello","customer_note_notify":1,"discount_amount":0,"discount_invoiced":0,"entity_id":1,"global_currency_code":"GBP","grand_total":36.39,"discount_tax_compensation_amount":0,"discount_tax_compensation_invoiced":0,"increment_id":"000000001","is_virtual":0,"order_currency_code":"GBP","protect_code":"91b4183927c7674b70700c4a49f6d6d7","quote_id":1,"shipping_amount":5,"shipping_description":"Flat Rate - Fixed","shipping_discount_amount":0,"shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amount":0,"shipping_incl_tax":5,"shipping_invoiced":5,"shipping_tax_amount":0,"state":"processing","status":"processing","store_currency_code":"GBP","store_id":1,"store_name":"Main Website\nMain Website 
....
```

but on my not working Magento server I get back:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 03 Jul 2018 21:38:53 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache   
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=nthuqggk44m3lfbe2us7juhkj1; expires=Tue, 03-Jul-2018 22:38:53 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/draft; 
domain=dedicated.qqqqq.co.uk; HttpOnly
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Length: 111

{"message":"Consumer is not authorized to access %resources","parameters": 
{"resources":"Magento_Sales::sales"}}
```

The tokens are coming from the API access token created from the integration menu. Interestingly I can use the admin username and password on the "broken" server to get an admin token, but that doesn't work either with the same result. Has anyone got any idea how I can debug this?

Comment: This is happening because you're trying to access orders using customer token but magento don't give access of  `Magento_Sales` module to customer type resource and you can achieve this from 2 ways.

Comment: I'm not trying to use a customer token, I am using an admin token or an integration token. I get the same error if I just replace the token with junk.

Comment: it's working fine with admin token.

Comment: <host>/rest/V1/integration/admin/token?username=aditya&password=aditya@123

Comment: it seems your admin token expired so you need to regenerate it. By default magento provide 4 hours of lifetime for admin token

Comment: no, I get the same problem with an admin token, even one I've just created.

Comment: have you checked the access allowed you that specific admin user, which you're using ?

Comment: Because the same url is working fine for me.

Comment: @Skippy we are having the same issue, have you made any progress?

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Comment: @Skippy This is hacky as hell but we got *something* working. If you're only using the M2 API internally this might help... in the file `vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/RequestValidator.php` you can replace checkPermissions() with ```private function checkPermissions() {
 $headers = getallheaders();
 if ($headers['Authorization'] !== 'Bearer hardcodedtokengoeshere') {
  throw new AuthorizationException("Invalid Token");
 }
}``` with a hardcoded auth token... this will disable the built in authn/z though, so use at your own risk.